# Is it possible to export a Plotly Dash app in a single standalone html file?

Tags: plotly-dash

In this html file, the data is included.

Also, there is **no** need for running a server for the user of the html file, and still all functionality is available.

The html file can for example be emailed and directly used by the receiver of that email by opening the html file in his browser.

I know it is possible with Bokeh, to export a standalone html with all the data and javascript callbacks.

Is this also possible with Plotly Dash? And if yes, how? (is there an example maybe somewhere?)

Comment: I'd encourage you to explore hosting your app on a service like Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible. What I would suggest instead is to use `pyinstaller` to generate an `.exe` (if you are on Windows). This file then can contain anything you like, including the data. 
When executed you can use something like `Timer(1, open_browser).start()` to open the users browser. with `def open_browser(): webbrowser.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:8050/')`
This solution works on the mashines of my colleagues no matter if they have python installed or not.

Best